# How to change the 1 column layout in wish list page in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to show the 1 column layout on the wishlist page only so that the left sidebar will hide. I have tried   `<update handle="1column.xml"/>` inside the wishlist_index_index.xml file but change is not reflecting.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Instead of:</strike>

```
<update handle="1column.xml"/>
```

<strike>change it to:</strike>

```
<update handle="1column"/>
```

Update:

Add

```
 layout="1column"
```

to:

`<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance".. .. ..>` tag

so it should look like:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: After the change, I have done with php bin/magento c:f but it's not working

Comment: @abhishek I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Change this **layout** value as you require.**(1column)**